# What are the building blocks of QTP 10 Automation Object Model

Tags: automated-testing, qtp

I need to understand QTP Automation Object Model. But I need to quick start just by understanding main building blocks. I understand taking a shortcut is not safe always. Yet, can anyone help me please? To repeat once again, I need to understand only the main things which will mostly help during automation.

Comment: Where have you searched so far for this information?  Looking up google for "qtp object model", I found a lot of results.  Did none of this help you?

Comment: @SuchitParikh Thanks. But can you cite any specific URL please? Which only contains the basic details.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this helps.
http://www.qtpworld.com/index.php?cid=77

The site in general is really good and on the left menu you have all the main blocks of QTP.

I do have to say though, there are the versions 11 and 11.50 which have some slight changes...

Thanks.